# How to search the feasible region in a smart way for the non closed-form optimization problem?

Tags: optimization, closed-form

A random variable X follows a discrete distribution D(P,I), where $P = \{p_1,p_2,...,p_n\}$ is the the list of the probability, and $I=\{i_1, i_2, \cdots, i_n\}$ is the list of values.  $T=X_1+X_2+\cdots+X_r$ is the sum of r independent identically distributed X, saying $T\sim S(P,r)$.

The objective function is

$$
g(P) = \frac{m-\beta P^TI}{1-\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(X) S(X|P,r) dX}
$$

- $r \in \{1,2,\cdots\}$ is given, for example $r = 11$
- $m > 0$, is given
- $\beta \gt 0$, is given
- $I=\{i_1, i_2, \cdots, i_n\}$, is given, and each element $i_j > 0$.
- $f(x)$ is an function which is solved by a machine learning algorithm, but the closed-form of $f(x)$ is not available.

My optimization problem is,

$$
\begin{equation*}
\begin{aligned}
& \underset{x}{\text{maxmize}}
& & g(P) \\
& \text{subject to}
& & \sum_{i=1}^n p_i = 1   \\
& & & 0 \le p1 \le a_1 \\
& & & \cdots \\
& & & 0 \le p_n \le a_n \\
\end{aligned}
\end{equation*}
$$
where $\{a_1,\cdots,a_n\}$ is given.

Given P, I can use monte carlo method to calculate the value of the objective function. However, the key problem is how to efficiently search the feasible region of P?

Comment: What do you mean by “efficiently”? The function $g$ is generally non-convex, so this is going to be NP hard.

Comment: @DavidM. If randomly sampling in the feasible region，I think it not efficiently. Is there any heuristic optimization method available to search efficiently？

Comment: Usually “efficiently” is used as a technical term to mean “in polynomial time.” Sounds like you just mean “in a smart way”?

Comment: @DavidM. Exactly！I will modify the title，thanks.

Comment: No problem. I think to get a good answer to this question you might need to know more about $f$ and the distribution

Comment: @DavidM. How about the particle swarm optimization algorithm？